# Transversing & replacing classes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wish to replace a class name for a child element (`ul`) of parent (`li.filetabs`) element. What I have done seems quite right but it's obviously not as the class is not being replaced.

**[UPDATED WITH JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ADesN/)**
Note for Jsfiddle: when you click once, it all works, click on the same navigation tab again and you see the drop down disappear and reappear...

```
var aFileTabs = $('.filetabs');
var curTab = $(this);
// this seems to give correct output 
var prevCurTab = $('.cTabActive').parent(); //(i.e. *jQuery(li.filetabs)*  )
// the following line is the problem line; Ive tried replacing the children with
// $('ul',prevCurTab)... but that doesnt work either... I must be doing something
// very basic wrong
$(prevCurTab).children().removeClass('cTabActive').addClass('cPrevTabActive');
$('ul', curTab).addClass ('cTabActive');
```

Edit: Apologies, I forgot the HTML, there is quite a bit more so only the first two navigation buttons html being shown to get the meaning across.

```
    <div id="filemenu">                     <!-- right tabs menu -->
        <ul id="fm_ul">
            <li class="filetabs">File
                <ul>
                    <li class="m_items"><a href="#"><span class="aHeading">New</span><span class="shortcutK">Ctrl-U</span></a></li>
                    <li class="m_items"><a href="#"><span class="aHeading">Open</span><span class="shortcutK">Ctrl-Z</span></a></li>
                    <li class="m_items"><a href="#"><span class="aHeading">Save</span><span class="shortcutK">Ctrl-T</span></a></li>
                    <li class="m_items"><a href="#"><span class="aHeading">Exit</span><span class="shortcutK">Ctrl-Q</span></a></li>
                </ul></li><li class="filetabs">Edit
<ul>
                    <li class="m_items"><a href="#"><span class="aHeading">Undo</span><span class="shortcutK">Ctrl-M</span></a></li>
                    <li class="m_items"><a href="#"><span class="aHeading">Redo</span><span class="shortcutK">Ctrl-S</span></a></li>
                    <li class="m_items"><a href="#"><span class="aHeading">Zoom In</span><span class="shortcutK">Ctrl-R</span></a></li>
                    <li class="m_items"><a href="#"><span class="aHeading">Zoom Out</span><span class="shortcutK">Ctrl-Q</span></a></li>

                </ul></li>
```

Comment: This is quite meaningless without your HTML markup. The code is syntactically correct... whether it is correct for your HTML, we cannot say.

Comment: Can you include the markup this is for? Confused that li is a parent of ul?

Comment: You mean like `$("li.filetabs ul").children()`?

Comment: My apologies, updated the que. @tandu, I want to grab the 'ul' under the li class="filetabs" (there are two of them in the example above, 1-File & 2-Edit. Hope this clarifies.

Comment: Yeah .. what I have does exactly that

Comment: where is your javascript code placed? in a function? What is $(this)?

Comment: @tandu, thanks but I need to be specific as I need to store the 'actioned' '.filetabs' class in variable prevCurTab.
Gavriel, yes its in a bigger function... this is a snippet of it, relevant to the problem

Comment: but what is $(this)? Give an example from your html? <ul id="fm_ul">? <li class="filetabs">File? <ul>? <li class="m_items">? <a href="#">? <span class="aHeading">?

Comment: Added JSFiddle to the post above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered in this separate post. Thanks Daniel.

[Jquery - manipulating classes in a simple dropdown menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10630511/jquery-manipulating-classes-in-a-simple-dropdown-menu)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I get this at all, but try:

```
$('.filetabs').on('click', function() {
    var aFileTabs = $('.filetabs'),
        curTab = $(this),
        prevCurTab = $('.cTabActive').parent();

    $('.cTabActive').removeClass('cTabActive').addClass('cPrevTabActive');
    $('ul', curTab).removeClass('cPrevTabActive').addClass ('cTabActive');
});
​
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/F2NwL/)

Comment: thanks adeneo. I think Im doing the same, however as you will see in the updated jsfiddle above, my menu does not disappear once it appears