# Jquery - manipulating classes in a simple dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

All,

I previously posted a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10605797/transversing-replacing-classes) but didnt get an answer (admittedly due to poor wording). Am re-posting after updating/ testing the code a bit more.

I want to build a simple drop down menu. [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gUh7V/8/).

**PROBLEM**:

The menu drops down & upon reclicking the tab, folds away nicely. However, when the menu is down & another tab is clicks, things go pear shaped, i.e. the other menu does not drop down.

Ive tested the jquery code extensively using firebug & have noticed a lot of abnormalities. E.g. I thought for my purpose, the jquery code:
`$('ul', curTab).***` would be the same as `$(curTab).children(0).***`, sometimes this code runs fine, other times it doesn't.

Consistently Ive noticed the 'addClass' & 'removeClass' method not adding & removing the class as intended.

The `if ($('.cTabActive')){...}` doesn't work, syntax error?

If I do `if ($('.cTabActive', aFileTabs)){...}`, this doesn't work either...

Im totally at my wit's end with this supposedly simple code. Help would be greatly appreciated.

Code:
(Please review the jsfiddle.net code above)

**HTML**:

```
  <div id="filemenu">                     <!-- right tabs menu -->
            <ul id="fm_ul">
                <li class="filetabs">File
                    <ul class='cDropDownItems'>
                        <li class="m_items"><a href="#"><span class="aHeading">New</span><span class="shortcutK">Ctrl-U</span></a></li>
                        <li class="m_items"><a href="#"><span class="aHeading">Open</span><span class="shortcutK">Ctrl-Z</span></a></li>
                    </ul></li><li class="filetabs">Edit
                    <ul class='cDropDownItems'>
                        <li class="m_items"><a href="#"><span class="aHeading">Undo</span><span class="shortcutK">Ctrl-M</span></a></li>

                    </ul></li><li class="filetabs cLastFileTabs">Settings
                    <ul class='cDropDownItems'>
                        <li class="m_items m_itemsCK" id="frontView"><a href="#"><img src="Img/tickB&W1.png" alt="tick" /><div class="filler"></div><span class="aHeading">Front View</span><span class="shortcutK">Ctrl-A</span></a></li>
                    </ul></li>
            </ul>
        </div>                    <!-- close -> 'filemenu' div -->
    </div>                    <!-- close -> 'menu_bars' div -->
```

**JAVASCRIPT**:

```
$('.filetabs').on('click', function (e) {
        function abc() {
            if ($(curTab).hasClass ('cLastFileTabs')) {
                $('ul', curTab).css ({left: '-66.6%'});
                $('ul',curTab).animate ({opacity: 1}, 125, 'linear');
            }    else     {
                $('ul', curTab).css ({left: 0});
                $('ul', curTab).animate ({opacity: 1}, 125, 'linear');
            }  }

    var aFileTabs = $('.filetabs');
    var curTab = $(this);
    if ($('.cTabActive'))   {
        var prevDropDown = $('.cTabActive').parent();
        var prevDDChild = $(prevDropDown).children(0);
        $(prevDDChild).removeClass('cTabActive').addClass('cPrevTabActive');  }
    if ($('ul',aFileTabs).hasClass('cPrevTabActive'))  {
        $('.cPrevTabActive',aFileTabs).animate ({opacity: 0}, 500, 'linear', function ()  {
            $('ul', aFileTabs).css ({left: '9999px'});
            $('ul', aFileTabs).removeClass ('cPrevTabActive');   }); }
    if ($(prevDropDown).get(0) !== $(curTab).get(0))  {
        $(curTab).children(0).addClass ('cTabActive');
        abc();
    } else  {
        return;
    }  });
```

Comment: `if ($('.cTabActive')) ` will never reach the else part. Use `if ($('.cTabActive').length) ` instead

Comment: @DhirajBodicherla, apparently not. When you click on another tab, both disappear. Then it takes two clicks to drop down the menu. 
Ori, thanks, length did solve that problem.

If you look at Firebug, you will notice that the class '.cTabActive' is not removed by the 'removeClass()' jquery method, nor is the class 'cPrevTabActive' added as per the 'addClass()' method.

Comment: Your code looks a little messy. You're checking if any of the tabs is `cPrevTab` (`if ($('ul',aFileTabs).hasClass('cPrevTabActive'))  {`), but then you're animating all of the tabs (`$(aFileTabs).children('ul').animate(`). It's important, especially when using animations, to have a tight grip on which tab is current, which tabs are animating, etc. and target specific elements

Comment: @ori, excellent point & thank you Ori. Yes you are right, when it already has a class given, I should refer to that class only and not animate all the 'uls'. Changing the code now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kayote,

Here is a working sample. I added .length(), redid the If logic, and use the setTimeout function so fade-in and fade-out does not conflict.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/N6uad/)
Good Luck!

Comment: Thank you so much Daniel. You made me see the light! Here is my cleaned-up JSfiddle code. http://jsfiddle.net/N6uad/1/